# Passing values from android to flutter but not from main activity

Tags: flutter, callback, flutter-platform-channel

i'm implementing a third party android sdk in flutter and i want a message to be passed from android to flutter when sdk starts

i have implemented the sdk using platform channel just need to work on the callback code. In the code there is a function called onChannelJoin i want to send message to flutter when this function is called

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.io/screen_record";

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
        new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                // TODO

                  if (call.method.equals("startScreenShare")) {

                      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , HelloAgoraScreenSharingActivity.class);

                      startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                  result.notImplemented();
                }
              }
          });

  }
}
```

ScreenSharingActivity

```
public class HelloAgoraScreenSharingActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AgoraScreenSharing";

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQ_ID_RECORD_AUDIO = 22;

    private ScreenCapture mScreenCapture;
    private GLRender mScreenGLRender;

    private RtcEngine mRtcEngine;

    private boolean mIsLandSpace = false;

    private void initModules() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        if (mScreenGLRender == null) {
            mScreenGLRender = new GLRender();
        }
        if (mScreenCapture == null) {
            mScreenCapture = new ScreenCapture(getApplicationContext(), mScreenGLRender, metrics.densityDpi);
        }

        mScreenCapture.mImgTexSrcConnector.connect(new SinkConnector<ImgTexFrame>() {
            @Override
            public void onFormatChanged(Object obj) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onFormatChanged " + obj.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFrameAvailable(ImgTexFrame frame) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onFrameAvailable " + frame.toString());

                if (mRtcEngine == null) {
                    return;
                }

                AgoraVideoFrame vf = new AgoraVideoFrame();
                vf.format = AgoraVideoFrame.FORMAT_TEXTURE_OES;
                vf.timeStamp = frame.pts;
                vf.stride = frame.mFormat.mWidth;
                vf.height = frame.mFormat.mHeight;
                vf.textureID = frame.mTextureId;
                vf.syncMode = true;
                vf.eglContext14 = mScreenGLRender.getEGLContext();
                vf.transform = frame.mTexMatrix;

                mRtcEngine.pushExternalVideoFrame(vf);
            }
        });

        mScreenCapture.setOnScreenCaptureListener(new ScreenCapture.OnScreenCaptureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStarted() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Screen Record Started");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int err) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onError " + err);
                switch (err) {
                    case ScreenCapture.SCREEN_ERROR_SYSTEM_UNSUPPORTED:
                        break;
                    case ScreenCapture.SCREEN_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int screenWidth = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int screenHeight = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        if ((mIsLandSpace && screenWidth < screenHeight) ||
                (!mIsLandSpace) && screenWidth > screenHeight) {
            screenWidth = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            screenHeight = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        }

        setOffscreenPreview(screenWidth, screenHeight);

        if (mRtcEngine == null) {
            try {
                mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(getApplicationContext(), "Agora_id", new IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onJoinChannelSuccess(String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onJoinChannelSuccess " + channel + " " + elapsed);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onWarning(int warn) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onWarning " + warn);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int err) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onError " + err);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAudioRouteChanged(int routing) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAudioRouteChanged " + routing);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));

                throw new RuntimeException("NEED TO check rtc sdk init fatal error\n" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }

            mRtcEngine.setChannelProfile(Constants.CHANNEL_PROFILE_LIVE_BROADCASTING);
            mRtcEngine.enableVideo();

            if (mRtcEngine.isTextureEncodeSupported()) {
                mRtcEngine.setExternalVideoSource(true, true, true);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Can not work on device do not supporting texture" + mRtcEngine.isTextureEncodeSupported());
            }

            mRtcEngine.setVideoProfile(Constants.VIDEO_PROFILE_360P, true);

            mRtcEngine.setClientRole(Constants.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER);
        }
    }

    private void deInitModules() {
        RtcEngine.destroy();
        mRtcEngine = null;

        if (mScreenCapture != null) {
            mScreenCapture.release();
            mScreenCapture = null;
        }

        if (mScreenGLRender != null) {
            mScreenGLRender.quit();
            mScreenGLRender = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set offscreen preview.
     *
     * @param width  offscreen width
     * @param height offscreen height
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     */
    public void setOffscreenPreview(int width, int height) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid offscreen resolution");
        }

        mScreenGLRender.init(width, height);
    }

    private void startCapture() {
        mScreenCapture.start();
    }

    private void stopCapture() {
        mScreenCapture.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_agora_screen_sharing);

    }

    public void onLiveSharingScreenClicked(View view) {


        Button button = (Button) view;
        boolean selected = button.isSelected();
        button.setSelected(!selected);

        if (button.isSelected()) {
            initModules();
            startCapture();

            String channel = "ss_test" + System.currentTimeMillis();
            channel = "ss_test";


            button.setText("stop");
            mRtcEngine.muteAllRemoteAudioStreams(true);
            mRtcEngine.muteAllRemoteVideoStreams(true);
            mRtcEngine.joinChannel(null, channel, "", 0);
        } else {

            button.setText("start");

            mRtcEngine.leaveChannel();

            stopCapture();
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        deInitModules();
    }
}
```

Dart Code

```
 const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.io/screen_record');
    try {
      final int result = await platform.invokeMethod('startScreenShare');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {}

    setState(() {

    });
```

Comment: and what do you have problems with?

Comment: i want to send a a success message to flutter but how i'm suppose to do that from screensharing actitvity

Comment: you have to call [Result#success](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.Result.html#success-java.lang.Object-) when `onChannelJoin` is called

Comment: Result#Sucess is defined in main activity how to call it from screenSharing

Comment: one way is to start ScreenSharing activity for result but i want the activity to be running even after join channel is called so any solution?

Comment: use `android.os.ResultReceiver` for example